# if the month is january date must be <= 31 then true or else false

Tags: sql-server-express

if the month is january then date must be <= 31 then validate true or false

select NO, if (month(colomn)=1)) (if Date(NO)<=31,'pass','fail,) ,'pass','fail') as result from table

select NO, if (month(colomn)=1)) (if Date(NO)<=31,'pass','fail,) ,'pass','fail') as result from table

2019/01/24  result true
2019/01/33  result false

Comment: please edit the question to add some more information like what have you tried so far, errors or results you get etc

Answer (score 0):

You should not be working with text dates in your SQL Server database if you can avoid it.  One simple tool available if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later is the `TRY_CONVERT` function.  `TRY_CONVERT` will attempt to parse your date string (in its current format, which it can handle), and will either return a `datetime` or `NULL`, the latter in the case when the date is bogus.  For example:

```
SELECT
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '2019/01/24') AS dt1,   -- 24/01/2019 00:00:00
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '2019/01/33') AS dt2;   -- NULL, can't be parsed
```

The value for `dt2` is `NULL`, since there is no 33rd day of January.